# Complex SQL Query with CROSS LEFT JOINS

Tags: sql, sql-server

Problem:

let's say i have 3 Common Table Expressions `CTE1`, `CTE2`, `CTE3`.
They all contain `MonthID`, `YearID`, `ProductID`, `StoreID`, `Amount`

I have tables `Years` &`Months` and `YearID` &`MonthID` are their Primary Keys.

I need to create a report that contains all the data for given period so i do something like this:

```
SELECT MonthID, YearID, ProductID, StoreID, Amount
FROM Years 
CROSS JOIN Months
CROSS JOIN Products
INNER JOIN Store on Store.StoreId = Products.ProductId
LEFT JOIN CTE1 On CTE1.MonthID = Months.MonthID AND CTE1.YearID = Years AND (CTE1.ProductID = Products.ProductId OR CTE.StoreID = Store.StoreID)
LEFT JOIN CTE2 On CTE2.MonthID = Months.MonthID AND CTE2.YearID = Years AND CTE2.ProductID = Products.ProductId AND CTE2.StoreID = Store.StoreID
LEFT JOIN CTE3 On CTE3.MonthID = Months.MonthID AND CTE3.YearID = Years AND CTE3.ProductID = Products.ProductId AND CTE3.StoreID = Store.StoreID
WHERE CTE1.Amount IS NOT NULL OR CTE2.Amount IS NOT NULL OR CTE3 IS NOT NULL
```

The thing is in the `CTE1` columns `StoreID` and `ProductID` can be `NULL`.
Maybe `ProductId`, maybe `StoreId`, maybe both columns are `NULL`.

And i still need those values to be in my report .... so how do I do it?

Comment: you could use coalesce and substitute the joined value basically resulting in a 1=1 so no record is omitted when a CTE1 ProductId or storeID is null.`AND coalesce(CTE1.ProductID,Products.productID) = Products.ProductId AND coalesce(CTE1.StoreID, store.storeID) = Store.StoreID`?  a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with data and expected results would go along way to ensuring we understand your problem.

Comment: What row from `Products INNER JOIN Store on Store.StoreId = Products.ProductId` must CTE1 match when 1) only CTE1.StoreID  is NULL, 2)only CTE1.ProductID is NULL, 3) both are NULL ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using coalesce on the CTE1 value with the join criteria.  This way when the CTE1.value is null; the value will be substitued for the value on the other side of the join.  The net result is when the CTE1 value is null it basically evaluates to a 1=1 statement and no record would be eliminated.

Granted performance will be sub optimal as you're using a function which may negate index use.

```
SELECT MonthID, YearID, ProductID, StoreID, Amount
FROM Years 
CROSS JOIN Months
CROSS JOIN Products
INNER JOIN Store on Store.StoreId = Products.ProductId
LEFT JOIN CTE1 
  ON CTE1.MonthID = Months.MonthID 
 AND CTE1.YearID = Years 
 AND coalesce(CTE1.ProductID, Products.ProductId) = Products.ProductId 
 AND coalesce(CTE1.StoreID, Store.StoreID) = Store.StoreID
LEFT JOIN CTE2 
  On CTE2.MonthID = Months.MonthID 
 AND CTE2.YearID = Years 
 AND CTE2.ProductID = Products.ProductId 
 AND CTE2.StoreID = Store.StoreID
LEFT JOIN CTE3 
  On CTE3.MonthID = Months.MonthID 
 AND CTE3.YearID = Years 
 AND CTE3.ProductID = Products.ProductId 
 AND CTE3.StoreID = Store.StoreID
WHERE CTE1.Amount IS NOT NULL 
   OR CTE2.Amount IS NOT NULL 
   OR CTE3 IS NOT NULL
```